# XSLT to replace element value if it starts-with a given prefix but leave the rest of the XML as is

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to do a simple "find-replace" in xslt but having trouble getting it to produce the correct output. I tried to follow other examples but unfortunately I haven't done much with XSLT and haven't been able to locate an example which does what I want to do.

I have the following XML:

```
<metadata>
<Permissions>site:abcdefg-123456-id1::{azeckoski}h,S,r</Permissions>
<Permissions>site:hjklqwe-098765-id2::{person2}h,S,r</Permissions>
<Permissions>playlist:5678::{azeckoski}h,S,r</Permissions>
<Permissions>playlist:7890::{azeckoski}H,s,r</Permissions>
<Permissions>playlist:1234::{person1}H,s,R</Permissions>
</metadata>
```

And the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:package="info:srw/extension/13/package-v1.0" >
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="metadata[starts-with(Permissions,'site:abcdefg-123456-id1::')]">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:text>site:abcdefg-123456-id1::{azeckoski}H,S,R</xsl:text>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would like to end up with the following XML:

```
<metadata>
<Permissions>site:abcdefg-123456-id1::{azeckoski}H,S,R</Permissions>
<Permissions>site:hjklqwe-098765-id2::{person2}h,S,r</Permissions>
<Permissions>playlist:5678::{azeckoski}h,S,r</Permissions>
<Permissions>playlist:7890::{azeckoski}H,s,r</Permissions>
<Permissions>playlist:1234::{person1}H,s,R</Permissions>
</metadata>
```

However I end up with this instead:

```
<metadata>site:abcdefg-123456-id1::{azeckoski}H,S,R</metadata>
```

I don't understand why the rest of the XML document is being wiped out. I thought I was using the identity template to keep everything else as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Permissions/text()[starts-with(.,'site:abcdefg-123456-id1::')]">
  <xsl:text>site:abcdefg-123456-id1::{azeckoski}H,S,R</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<metadata>
    <Permissions>site:abcdefg-123456-id1::{azeckoski}h,S,r</Permissions>
    <Permissions>site:hjklqwe-098765-id2::{person2}h,S,r</Permissions>
    <Permissions>playlist:5678::{azeckoski}h,S,r</Permissions>
    <Permissions>playlist:7890::{azeckoski}H,s,r</Permissions>
    <Permissions>playlist:1234::{person1}H,s,R</Permissions>
</metadata>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<metadata>
   <Permissions>site:abcdefg-123456-id1::{azeckoski}H,S,R</Permissions>
   <Permissions>site:hjklqwe-098765-id2::{person2}h,S,r</Permissions>
   <Permissions>playlist:5678::{azeckoski}h,S,r</Permissions>
   <Permissions>playlist:7890::{azeckoski}H,s,r</Permissions>
   <Permissions>playlist:1234::{person1}H,s,R</Permissions>
</metadata>
```

**Your problem was that** you do not process (apply templates to) the children of `metadata`.

Comment: I took out the strip-space and other formatting changes but otherwise this worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The function `start-with()` [expect a string as first argument](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_starts-with.html), not a node(). Your match rule was incorrect. It should be :

```
<xsl:template match="metadata/Permissions[starts-with(./text(),'site:abcdefg-123456-id1::')]">
...
</xsl:template>
```

Here, the string tested to see if it start-with 'site:abcdefg-123456-id1::' is `metadata/Permissions/text()`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the match was actually working fine, it was just the wrong output

Comment: The match might have been matching the metadata element, but it was only processing its first child.